# Other ways of paying gas different than Ether?

Tags: ether, gas, fees, transfer, basic-attention-token

I've been trying to transfer my BATs from my ledger to the exchange address, only to discover that I haven't enough coins in the ETH parent wallet to pay the gas ..

I had some ETHER until a couple of weeks ago but I withdrew them to the exchange and now I am over..

now.. I don't want to buy ether at the moment since it's so expensive and transactions are too..

today network fees are not so expensive, but I still have to buy ETH, transfer ecc ..

[image: screen]

so, as a rule, is there another way pay gas other than through ethereum coins?

couldn't I be able to just pay in BATs??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Ethereum does not support using any other token as a gas currency except ETH.

Some [custom wallets are working to support gas station network](https://docs.opengsn.org/) that would allow middleman to pay ETH on behalf of you. But in this case you end up paying the middleman the market rate of currency conversion.